# Is there a way to enclose multiple event declarations on a single [<CLIEvent>] block?

Tags: events, f#, annotations

It is a little tedious to write:

```
let e1 = Event<_>()
let e... = Event<_>()
let en = Event<_>()

[<CLIEvent>]
member this.E1 = e1.Publish
[<CLIEvent>]
member this.E... = e....Publish
[<CLIEvent>]
member this.En = en.Publish
```

In the code, I show how I need to write `n` `[<CLIEvent>]`, 1 for each event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[<CLIEvent>]` is not a "block", it's an *attribute*.

An attribute applies to member immediately after it, so no, you can't have same `[<CLIEvent>]` attribute applied to multiple members.

But you can put them on the same line, if that helps:

```
[<CLIEvent>] member this.E1 = e1.Publish
[<CLIEvent>] member this.E... = e....Publish
[<CLIEvent>] member this.En = en.Publish
```

Comment: It helps a little, thanks a lot. I just introduced the word "block" to express the idea of what I was looking for.